# how to inject text into a textbox with firefox extension

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, xul

This question was probably asked few time by now... but I didn't find any solution in the last 2 days so I'm asking it in here.
I need to inject some text into a textbox that has an ID and I already know it. the scenario is like that:

- The user insert a text into the textbox inside my toolbar.
- The user clicks on a button in my toolar.
- The function in the button should redirect the user to a new page in the background, inject a text into a specified textbox and click a button in that webpage.
- Return a link that is generated on the webpage.

I know how to open a new webpage. now all is left is the rest.
I can't seem to inject the text into the specified textbox.

Also to note, I can't use greasemonkey on this project and that's why I will have to write everything I'll need to write.

If you can direct me to the starting point for this problem it would be nice.

Answer (score 0):

The textbox is XUL textbox or html textarea?

It look like your scenario is simulate submit a form in background, why not just directly create a XMLHttpRequest to do this, no need to interactive with UI.

**Update:**

If it is a XUL textbox, you can use [value property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XUL/textbox#p-textbox.value)

```
var textbox = window.document.getElementById(textboxId);
if (textbox) {
    textbox.value = 'your text';
}
```

Comment: it's a xul textbox, and if you have any link to refence me on how to use it, it would be awesome.

Comment: You can use the `value` property.